# Getting negative autoincrement value in Delphi CE against Sqlite3

Tags: database, sqlite, delphi

I have looked and maybe I don't know where to look, but here is my situation.  I converted a working .mdb database to SQlite using a trial app: ESF Database Migration Toolkit. I migrated all the data with a last autoincremented ID of 263.  When I tried to insert any data into the .db using Delphi CE, the autoincrement field didn't work, saying the ID field needed a value.  I looked at the table and it had a constraint for the field. I removed the constraint using SQliteUI, redid the ID making it a PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTOINCREMENT and now can add data, but it gives me a negative ID (-3).  If I put this in SQLiteUI directly it gives a NULL value until the table is refreshed and I get the correct next ID (264).  What could I be doing wrong? Should I have not migrated with data? Remade the table in SQLiteUI?  I didn't want to have to manually reenter all that data.  Thanks

```
CREATE TABLE wines ( 
  wineID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL, 
  winename VARCHAR (175), 
  winery VARCHAR (200), 
  varietal VARCHAR (200), 
  winetype VARCHAR (150), 
  incellar INTEGER DEFAULT 0, 
  vintage VARCHAR (10), 
  grapes VARCHAR (150), 
  pricepaid NUMERIC (10, 2) DEFAULT 0,
  winelabel BLOB, 
  wherestored VARCHAR (100), 
  rating VARCHAR (10), 
  datepurchased DATETIME, 
  foodpairing VARCHAR (255), 
  region VARCHAR (150), 
  regionalstyle VARCHAR (150), 
  country VARCHAR (150), 
  mynotes VARCHAR (255) 
)
```

Comment: Post the table's CREATE statement as it is now.

Comment: CREATE TABLE wines (     wineID        INTEGER         PRIMARY KEY ASC AUTOINCREMENT  NOT NULL,  winename      VARCHAR (175),  winery VARCHAR (200), varietal      VARCHAR (200), winetype      VARCHAR (150), incellar  INTEGER         DEFAULT 0,, vintage       VARCHAR (10),   grapes  VARCHAR (150),  pricepaid     NUMERIC (10, 2) DEFAULT 0, winelabel  BLOB,   wherestored   VARCHAR (100),
    rating        VARCHAR (10),  datepurchased DATETIME, foodpairing   VARCHAR (255), region        VARCHAR (150), regionalstyle VARCHAR (150), country   VARCHAR (150),  mynotes       VARCHAR (255) );

Comment: Instead of posting in a comment, you should EDIT your post to add that information. Also format your question so that it is more readable.

Comment: @ fpiette, I'm sorry don't use this enough to know how to do that. I was answering @forpas's comment.

Comment: Under your question, there is a line with a few links. Click the "edit" link.

Comment: @ fpiette,  Thanks

Comment: *...but it gives me a negative ID (-3)* how do you get this id? It may be related to Delphi code and not SQLite.

Comment: @forpas, I'm using FireDAC database engine

Comment: Since (even after refresh) you get the correct id, this means that the column's definition is correct. So the negative value that you get is the result of the code in your app (Delphi with FireDAC).

Comment: @forpas  Thanks for your help